# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error while running app

Tags: swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have this code and whenever i am running app it gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I printed values for self.state and newValue.rawValue by po in terminal of XCode and they have values but i dont understand why i am getting **"EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error and "CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named for entity Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead"**. I am getting this error when I do following

```
d.change = .n  //d is just instance of class from where state comes
```

What can be a reason?

```
var change: A {         
        get { return A(rawValue: self.state) ?? .n }
        set { self.state = newValue.rawValue }
    }

enum A: Int16 { 
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
    case c = 3
    case n = 90
}
```

state is a property of class which inherits from NSManagedObject

```
@NSManaged var state: Int16
```

Comment: What is the initial value of self.state? How is A defined?

Comment: `A(rawValue: self.state` returns an optional, `?? .none` unwraps it if it's not `nil`, otherwise defaults to `.none` (a.k.a. `nil`), then `!` force unwraps it, which could be `nil`. What did you expect?

Comment: @vacawama 1,
 enum A: Int16 {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
    case c = 3
    case none = 90
}

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov i have put a breakpoint at getter it just jump to the setter it does not reach the A(rawValue: self.state )

Comment: "Unable to load class named for entity Class not found": Please  show the settings of the entity (Codegen, Module ...) in your Core Data model.